# Xamarin: Picker Title dont change programmatically

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am working on an iOS App, written in C#, Xamarin. I use a Picker in MVVM Architecture and want to change the pickers title. 
but when i change the Pickers Title with OnAddMaterial, the Title doesnt change.

The ViewModel:

```
private void OnAddNewMaterial()
        {
            SelectedMaterialIndex = -1;
            MaterialPickerTitle = "New Material";
        }

    private string _materialPickerTitle { get; set; }
            public string MaterialPickerTitle
            {
                get { return _materialPickerTitle; }
                set
                {
                    _materialPickerTitle = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();

                }
            }
```

The View:

```
<Picker Title="{Binding MaterialPickerTitle}" Margin="12,4,4,4" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding Materials}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMaterial}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedMaterialIndex}" />
```

I use Visual Studio 2019.

EDIT:
when i am initializing the view, i set the title from the Picker. that works great. After that, i am assigning Objects to the ItemSource from Picker. When i am trying to set the pickers title after that it doesnt works.

Comment: does the ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: yes, all other values are updating in the view after i change them in the viewmodel. i am using mvvmhelpers

Comment: Have you tried setting the binding mode of the title in TwoWay?

Comment: i tried it, no changes.

Comment: I solved it. Apparently you can't change the title after the Picker's SelectedItem has been set.
Now I no longer add a SelectedItem to the picker but set the title directly.

Comment: ok - the problem persists. After i change the selectedItem, i I can’t change the title anymore. Before that without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a demo and the title of Picker can be changed after I change the selectedItem. Here is the code you can refer:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    List<string> monkeyList = new List<string>();

    TestModel model = new TestModel();
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        monkeyList.Add("Baboon");
        monkeyList.Add("Capuchin Monkey");
        monkeyList.Add("Blue Monkey");
        monkeyList.Add("Squirrel Monkey");
        monkeyList.Add("Golden Lion Tamarin");
        monkeyList.Add("Howler Monkey");
        monkeyList.Add("Japanese Macaque");

        picker.ItemsSource = monkeyList;

        model.MaterialPickerTitle = "123";
        model.SelectedMaterialIndex = 2;
        BindingContext = model;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        monkeyList.Add("Baboonww");

        model.SelectedMaterialIndex = -1;
        model.MaterialPickerTitle = "456";

    }
}

class TestModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public TestModel()
    {

    }

    string materialPickerTitle;
    public string MaterialPickerTitle
    {
        set
        {
            if (materialPickerTitle != value)
            {
                materialPickerTitle = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MaterialPickerTitle"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return materialPickerTitle;
        }
    }

    int selectedMaterialIndex;
    public int SelectedMaterialIndex
    {
        set
        {
            if (selectedMaterialIndex != value)
            {
                selectedMaterialIndex = value;

                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedMaterialIndex"));
                }
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return selectedMaterialIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

And in xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="click to change title" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    <Picker x:Name="picker"
    Title="{Binding MaterialPickerTitle}"
    SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedMaterialIndex}"
    TitleColor="Red">
    </Picker>
</StackLayout>
```

Please check your bindings in your project. Add some breakPoints to debug if the title changes. I also upload my sample project [here](https://github.com/XfHua/Picker-Title).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! now I have it